# Dynamic partials and cache_digests

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code in my contactsheet/preview view:

```
= render :partial => @contactsheet.choose_partial.first
```

choose_template is a function for selecting the right partial. choose_partial() returns an array with one element (the partial name). It works fine. Now, I want to use cache_digests for this partial, I added the cache code in the partial.

But when I run the rake task
`rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies TEMPLATE=contactsheets/preview` for getting the dependencies, it outputs

```
[
  "contactsheets/@contactsheet.choose_template.first"
]
```

The expression isn't evaluated and the dependency is wrong. How do I correct this dependency?

Comment: I think you can solve this with explicit dependencies. See the last section of the README: https://github.com/rails/cache_digests

Comment: @Kaeros Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work either. I've circumvent this issue by listing all possible dependencies explicitly.